# clojure: If I am creating an operator staircase, how do I define the identity for the operator in general?

Tags: clojure, operators

I was thinking about how you can build `*` out of `+`, and `+` out of `inc` ultimately, then going in the other direction applying the same pattern of using the lower function `(f a b)` b times you get a staircase of hyper-multiplicative functions of ever increasing hyperness.  So I decided to try and code an infinite list of ever increasing hyperoperators.  I came up with this, which is pretty close! :

```
(defn operator-staircase
  []
  (iterate
   (fn [f]
     (fn [a b]
       (loop [bottom b
              result a]
         (if (>= 0 bottom)
           result
           (recur
            (dec bottom)
            (f a result))))))
   (fn [a b]
     (inc b))))

(def ops (operator-staircase))
((nth ops 0) 3 5) ;; -->  6  (inc is arity one so it must ignore one of the args?)
((nth ops 1) 3 5) ;; -->  8  (correct addition)
((nth ops 2) 3 5) ;; -->  18  (oops, one off!  otherwise correctly multiplies.)  
                                Basically implements (fn [a b] (* a (inc b)))
((nth ops 3) 3 5) ;; ---->  1092 (Wow)
```

The only thing I don't know how to do is define the initial `result` in a general way!  I just made it `a` because it kind of works, but for addition for example it must be 0, whereas multiplication should be 1.

How do I define the initial value of `result` in the loop above so that it works in all cases in a general way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not really sure whether it's appropriate for what you're trying to achieve, but could you take advantage of the fact that `(+)` is 0 and `(*)` is 1?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation. You have to define a few more base cases. Note that translating the definition directly into recursive code would blow the stack even at small values, and iterative implementations will take a very, very long time to calculate even at small values. See [table of values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation#Tables_of_values) for some feel of how fast this grows.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to start from `inc`, you can only meaningfully define unary operators. So the 0th step is "add one"; the 1st step is "N times: add one", which is basically `#(+ % %)`; the 2nd step is "N times: add N", which is `#(* % %)`; the 3rd step is "N times: multiply by N", which is `#(pow % %)`...and so on.

If you want to define binary operators, I think you just start from `+` rather than from `inc`, and derive the rest just as you did.

Comment: "Lifting" `inc` into a binary function that ignores the first arg seems to work, I just don't know how to define the base value for each level!

Answer (score 0):

I think what amalloy says is correct. Here's my version of your sequence, starting at `+` as suggested by amalloy. The other difference with yours is that my counter variable starts at `(dec b)` instead of at `b`. The reason is that if you think of e.g. `a*3` as "`a` added to itself 3 times", this is still only 2 applications of the addition function (i.e. `a+a+a`). With these changes, I get the results I think you're expecting.

```
(def operator-staircase
  (iterate
    (fn [f]
      (fn [a b]
        (loop [acc a
               counter (dec b)]
        (if (>= 0 counter)
          acc
          (recur (f a acc) (dec counter))))))
    +))

;; in comments, * is multiplication, ** is exponentiation (chained multiplication), *** is chained exponentiation, etc
(println ((nth operator-staircase 0) 3 2)) ; 5 = 3+2 = (inc (inc 3)))
(println ((nth operator-staircase 1) 3 2)) ; 6 = 3*2 = 3+3
(println ((nth operator-staircase 2) 3 2)) ; 9 = 3**2 = 3*3 = 3+3+3
(println ((nth operator-staircase 3) 3 2)) ; 27 = 3***2 = 3**3 = 3*3*3
;(println ((nth operator-staircase 4) 3 2)) ; takes too long to compute, but presumably 7625597484987 = 3****2 = 3***3 = 3**(3**3)
(println ((nth operator-staircase 0) 2 3)) ; 5 = 2+3 = (inc (inc (inc 2)))
(println ((nth operator-staircase 1) 2 3)) ; 6 = 2*3 = 2+2+2
(println ((nth operator-staircase 2) 2 3)) ; 8 = 2**3 = 2*2*2 = 2+2+2+2
(println ((nth operator-staircase 3) 2 3)) ; 16 = 2***3 = 2**(2**2) = 2*2*2*2
```

Let's break the first few iterations down a bit:

```
(defn apply-n-times [f n arg]
  (if (= n 0) arg
    (recur f (dec n) (f arg))))

(defn plus [m n]
  (apply-n-times inc n m))

(defn times [m n]
  (apply-n-times (partial plus m) (dec n) m))

(defn exp [m n]
  (apply-n-times (partial times m) (dec n) m))

(defn expexp [m n]
  (apply-n-times (partial exp m) (dec n) m))
```

Again, it's necessary to apply `(dec n)` times rather than `n`. If I applied `n` times, then the third arg would have to be 0 for `times`, and 1 for `exp`, instead of `m` for all of them, so there would be no uniformity.

The `apply-n-times` function allows us to define your operator staircase a little more concisely:

```
(def os2
  (iterate
    (fn [f]
      (fn [m n]
        (apply-n-times (partial f m) (dec n) m)))
    +))
```

This one gives the same results as the previous definition. But I still couldn't go one step further down and define `+` in terms of `inc` in the same sequence. If you look at the difference between `plus` and the other functions above (`times`, `exp`, `expexp`), I think you can see the structure is not the same.